# Dart Doc Comments broken in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I'm looking over the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#markdown) on doc comments in Dart, and came across the following:

```dart
/// Links can be:
///
/// * https://www.just-a-bare-url.com
/// * [with the URL inline](https://google.com)
/// * [or separated out][ref link]
///
/// [ref link]: https://google.com
///
```

But I've noticed a couple of things when I'm trying this in IntelliJ:

1. I can't get the link to show as a hyperlink (when pressing `ctrl + q` to open documentation) when part of a list item (by starting the line with any of these `1.` `*` `-` `+`)
2. I can't get the 1st or 3rd forms of link expression to work, even outside of a list.

I'm trying to add a doc comment to a method that uses a dependency, and link to the dependency in the comment. Here's the comment that I have:

```
/// Doing dot product with a layer of neurons and multiple inputs
///
/// Associated YT NNFS tutorial: [Part-3](*youtube link here*)
///
/// This uses the [ml_linalg][1] dependency. You can also use the [linalg][2] dependency
///
/// [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/ml_linalg
///
/// [2]: https://pub.dev/packages/linalg
```

Here's a screenshot of how IntelliJ renders the documentation. The youtube link shows fine (using the second approach from the documentation) but clutters up the doc comment for the writers/editors of the docs. But as you can see, the third form doesn't work at all. The text in the square brackets isn't turned into a link and the text in second set of square brackets is just concatenated onto the text of the first.

[image]

If anyone knows how I can add links to my doc comments as part of a list, as well as put a marker to the link and have the full URL at the end of the doc comment as in the 3rd example given, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance

Comment: @dev-aentgs Did you just try to link me to the same documentation that I already linked to in my question? I even explicitly copied the portion of the documentation I am struggling with. This documentation is precisely where the question comes from. Please read through the question carefully and let me know if you can help.

Comment: Sorry. i accidentally overlooked the documentation link.

Comment: I'm unsure if the problem is with the documentation on the Dart website or if the problem is with IntelliJ or if the problem is with the Dart plugin for IntelliJ or if the problem is with my version of the Dart SDK or something. Try the same doc comment I have here and see if you encounter the same issue with your setup

Comment: Yes, Trying out now

Comment: I am getting the same issue as you are. Android Studio 4.0, flutter plugin 47.0.2, Dart plugin 193.7361

Comment: This sounds like a problem with IntelliJ. The format is completely normal [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/)/markdown format, but that only works in an editor if the editor is aware of that and can understand the format. I do not believe that the Dart language server is doing anything for comment links.

Comment: @Irn Since support for Dart is brought into IntelliJ via the Dart plug-in, do you think the issue is with the IntelliJ *plug-in*, or with the IntelliJ *application*?

Comment: @loganrussell48 the first type can be achieved by wrapping  in `<` `>` like `<https://pub.dev/packages/ml_linalg>` . I am still not able to get the 3rd type; ref link to work.